# Задача о рюкзаке с ограниченным числом предметов

Tags: python, алгоритм, динамическое-программирование

Задача найти наилучший расклад рюкзака, зная не только веса и стоимость, но и максимальное количество каждого товара.

```
for i in range(1, n + 1):
    for j in range(0, W + 1):
        for cnt in range(min(k[i], W // a[i]) + 1):
            if a[i] * cnt <= j:
                dp[i][j] = max(dp[i][j], dp[i - 1][j - a[i] * cnt] + c[i] * cnt)
```

Я нашёл данный код в интернете и я уверен, что он работает, но я не понимаю что в массиве `dp` является ответом и какова база индукции?

Comment: Вы понимаете что лежит в `dp[i][j]`?

Comment: Мы храним там максимальную стоимость набора как я понимаю

Comment: Вопрос про рюкзак уже не первый раз мелькает на SO. Ищите.

Answer (score 0):

Вы почему-то не привели описание того, что хранится в `a,c,k`

OK, давайте посмотрим на код.
Имеется таблица, номер строки `i` в которой соответствует номеру товара.
Номер колонки соответствует текущему весу (общий максимум `W`).

Теперь перебираем возможное количество единиц `i`-го товара, действуют два ограничения - количества `k[i]` и на возможный оставшийся вес (единица весит `a[i]`)

Сумма в  `dp[i][j]` складывается из цены товара `c[i]`, помноженной на количество, и суммы в ряду выше, взятой из колонки, меньшей на вес набора текущего товара. При этом выбираем лучший вариант по стоимости при использовании разных количеств текущего товара.

Таким образом, в последнем ряду будет набор стоимостей, из которых нужно выбрать максимум

```
Best = max(dp[n])
```

Comment: @Alexander Удалось разобраться?