# Задача про ограниченный рюкзак на С++

Tags: c++, динамическое-программирование

Нашел хорошее решение задачи о рюкзаке ( уложить как можно большее число ценных вещей в рюкзак при условии, что вместимость рюкзака ограничена. ) на С++

https://rosettacode.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem/Bounded#C++
Ссылка на решения.

Можете подсказать, как можно исправить код, приведенный там, если рюкзак ограничен не только весом, но и количеством предметов которые в него можно положить ?

То есть, с текущими предметами из этого примера, в ответе получается список из 14 предметов.
А как сделать, что бы рюкзак, помимо веса, был еще и ограничен, например 10ю предметами ?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <stdexcept>
#include <memory>
#include <sys/time.h>

using std::cout;
using std::endl;

class StopTimer
{
public:
    StopTimer(): begin_(getUsec()) {}
    unsigned long long getTime() const { return getUsec() - begin_; }
private:
    static unsigned long long getUsec()
    {//...you might want to use something else under Windows
        timeval tv;
        const int res = ::gettimeofday(&tv, 0);
        if(res)
            return 0;
        return tv.tv_usec + 1000000 * tv.tv_sec;
    }
    unsigned long long begin_;
};

struct KnapsackTask
{
    struct Item
    {
        std::string name;
        unsigned w, v, qty;
        Item(): w(), v(), qty() {}
        Item(const std::string& iname, unsigned iw, unsigned iv, unsigned iqty):
            name(iname), w(iw), v(iv), qty(iqty)
        {}
    };
    typedef std::vector<Item> Items;
    struct Solution
    {
        unsigned v, w;
        unsigned long long iterations, usec;
        std::vector<unsigned> n;
        Solution(): v(), w(), iterations(), usec() {}
    };
    //...
    KnapsackTask(): maxWeight_(), totalWeight_() {}
    void add(const Item& item)
    {
        const unsigned totalItemWeight = item.w * item.qty;
        if(const bool invalidItem = !totalItemWeight)
            throw std::logic_error("Invalid item: " + item.name);
        totalWeight_ += totalItemWeight;
        items_.push_back(item);
    }
    const Items& getItems() const { return items_; }
    void setMaxWeight(unsigned maxWeight) { maxWeight_ = maxWeight; }
    unsigned getMaxWeight() const { return std::min(totalWeight_, maxWeight_); }

private:
    unsigned maxWeight_, totalWeight_;
    Items items_;
};

class BoundedKnapsackRecursiveSolver
{
public:
    typedef KnapsackTask Task;
    typedef Task::Item Item;
    typedef Task::Items Items;
    typedef Task::Solution Solution;

    void solve(const Task& task)
    {
        Impl(task, solution_).solve();
    }
    const Solution& getSolution() const { return solution_; }
private:
    class Impl
    {
        struct Candidate
        {
            unsigned v, n;
            bool visited;
            Candidate(): v(), n(), visited(false) {}
        };
        typedef std::vector<Candidate> Cache;
    public:
        Impl(const Task& task, Solution& solution):
            items_(task.getItems()),
            maxWeight_(task.getMaxWeight()),
            maxColumnIndex_(task.getItems().size() - 1),
            solution_(solution),
            cache_(task.getMaxWeight() * task.getItems().size()),
            iterations_(0)
        {}
        void solve()
        {
            if(const bool nothingToSolve = !maxWeight_ || items_.empty())
                return;
            StopTimer timer;
            Candidate candidate;
            solve(candidate, maxWeight_, items_.size() - 1);
            convertToSolution(candidate);
            solution_.usec = timer.getTime();
        }
    private:
        void solve(Candidate& current, unsigned reminderWeight, const unsigned itemIndex)
        {
            ++iterations_;

            const Item& item(items_[itemIndex]);

            if(const bool firstColumn = !itemIndex)
            {
                const unsigned maxQty = std::min(item.qty, reminderWeight/item.w);
                current.v = item.v * maxQty;
                current.n = maxQty;
                current.visited = true;
            }
            else
            {
                const unsigned nextItemIndex = itemIndex - 1;
                {
                    Candidate& nextItem = cachedItem(reminderWeight, nextItemIndex);
                    if(!nextItem.visited)
                        solve(nextItem, reminderWeight, nextItemIndex);
                    current.visited = true;
                    current.v = nextItem.v;
                    current.n = 0;
                }
                if(reminderWeight >= item.w)
                {
                    for (unsigned numberOfItems = 1; numberOfItems <= item.qty; ++numberOfItems)
                    {
                        reminderWeight -= item.w;
                        Candidate& nextItem = cachedItem(reminderWeight, nextItemIndex);
                        if(!nextItem.visited)
                            solve(nextItem, reminderWeight, nextItemIndex);

                        const unsigned checkValue = nextItem.v + numberOfItems * item.v;
                        if ( checkValue > current.v)
                        {
                            current.v = checkValue;
                            current.n = numberOfItems;
                        }
                        if(!(reminderWeight >= item.w))
                            break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        void convertToSolution(const Candidate& candidate)
        {
            solution_.iterations = iterations_;
            solution_.v = candidate.v;
            solution_.n.resize(items_.size());

            const Candidate* iter = &candidate;
            unsigned weight = maxWeight_, itemIndex = items_.size() - 1;
            while(true)
            {
                const unsigned currentWeight = iter->n * items_[itemIndex].w;
                solution_.n[itemIndex] = iter->n;
                weight -= currentWeight;
                if(!itemIndex--)
                    break;
                iter = &cachedItem(weight, itemIndex);
            }
            solution_.w = maxWeight_ - weight;
        }
        Candidate& cachedItem(unsigned weight, unsigned itemIndex)
        {
            return cache_[weight * maxColumnIndex_ + itemIndex];
        }
        const Items& items_;
        const unsigned maxWeight_;
        const unsigned maxColumnIndex_;
        Solution& solution_;
        Cache cache_;
        unsigned long long iterations_;
    };
    Solution solution_;
};

void populateDataset(KnapsackTask& task)
{
    typedef KnapsackTask::Item Item;
    task.setMaxWeight( 400 );
    task.add(Item("map",9,150,1));
    task.add(Item("compass",13,35,1));
    task.add(Item("water",153,200,2));
    task.add(Item("sandwich",50,60,2));
    task.add(Item("glucose",15,60,2));
    task.add(Item("tin",68,45,3));
    task.add(Item("banana",27,60,3));
    task.add(Item("apple",39,40,3));
    task.add(Item("cheese",23,30,1));
    task.add(Item("beer",52,10,3));
    task.add(Item("suntancream",11,70,1));
    task.add(Item("camera",32,30,1));
    task.add(Item("T-shirt",24,15,2));
    task.add(Item("trousers",48,10,2));
    task.add(Item("umbrella",73,40,1));
    task.add(Item("w-trousers",42,70,1));
    task.add(Item("w-overclothes",43,75,1));
    task.add(Item("note-case",22,80,1));
    task.add(Item("sunglasses",7,20,1));
    task.add(Item("towel",18,12,2));
    task.add(Item("socks",4,50,1));
    task.add(Item("book",30,10,2));
}

int main()
{
    KnapsackTask task;
    populateDataset(task);

    BoundedKnapsackRecursiveSolver solver;
    solver.solve(task);
    const KnapsackTask::Solution& solution = solver.getSolution();

    cout << "Iterations to solve: " << solution.iterations << endl;
    cout << "Time to solve: " << solution.usec << " usec" << endl;
    cout << "Solution:" << endl;
    for (unsigned i = 0; i < solution.n.size(); ++i)
    {
        if (const bool itemIsNotInKnapsack = !solution.n[i])
            continue;
        cout << "  " << solution.n[i] << ' ' << task.getItems()[i].name << " ( item weight = " << task.getItems()[i].w << " )" << endl;
    }

    cout << "Weight: " << solution.w << " Value: " << solution.v << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: как по мне, просто куча кода с непонятным алгоритмом. вот [решение](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1520387/%d0%97%d0%b0%d0%b4%d0%b0%d1%87%d0%b0-%d0%be-%d1%80%d1%8e%d0%ba%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%ba%d0%b5-%d1%81-%d0%be%d0%b3%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%bc-%d1%87%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%bc-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%bc%d0%b5%d1%82%d0%be%d0%b2) в 6 строчек методом ДП.

Comment: Просто все примеры методом динамического программирования, которые я нашел,  считают, что в рюкзак можно класть сколь угодно много предметов.